# Dexie.js db instances on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, indexeddb, dexie

I'm currently trying [dexie.js](http://dexie.org/) to wrap over indexedDb for a simple usecase on my javascript app. On iOS Safari it seems to be creating multiple instances of a database like so:

[image: iOS Safari indexedDb via dexie.js]

I figure that dexie is creating a new db instance for every write transaction which is quite odd behavior. Is there a wrapper with cross-browser implementation over indexeddb that works? Especially on iOS Safari!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need something that will work with iOS, I suggest you take a look at localForage on Github. It has a very simple API and was designed for mobile use, so it has fallbacks for devices that might not support IndexedDB.

https://localforage.github.io/localForage/